# Split 1 row into multiple rows by range on 2 column values in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

Does anyone know a good way in Scala to explode a row into multiple rows based on a range from two columns?

For example, for the input dataframe:

```
start_ip_int | end_ip_int | country | city
100          | 105        | USA     | Boston
```

The expected output dataframe is:

```
start_ip_int | end_ip_int | country | city   | ip
100          | 105        | USA     | Boston | 100
100          | 105        | USA     | Boston | 101
100          | 105        | USA     | Boston | 102
100          | 105        | USA     | Boston | 103
100          | 105        | USA     | Boston | 104
100          | 105        | USA     | Boston | 105
```

So here one row got split into 6 rows based on the range of columns `start_ip_int` and `end_ip_int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on `Spark 2.4+`, use [`sequence`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@sequence(start:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,stop:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) with the IP integer range as arguments to generate an `ArrayType` column, followed by `explode`-ing it:

```
val df = Seq((100, 105, "USA", "Boston")).
  toDF("start_ip_int", "end_ip_int", "country", "city")

df.withColumn("ip", explode(sequence($"start_ip_int", $"end_ip_int"))).show
// +------------+----------+-------+------+---+                                    
// |start_ip_int|end_ip_int|country|  city| ip|
// +------------+----------+-------+------+---+
// |         100|       105|    USA|Boston|100|
// |         100|       105|    USA|Boston|101|
// |         100|       105|    USA|Boston|102|
// |         100|       105|    USA|Boston|103|
// |         100|       105|    USA|Boston|104|
// |         100|       105|    USA|Boston|105|
// +------------+----------+-------+------+---+
```

For older Spark version, consider creating a simple UDF to mimic the `sequence` function:

```
val rangeSequence = udf{ (lower: Int, upper: Int) =>
  Seq.iterate(lower, upper - lower + 1)(_ + 1)
}

// Applying the UDF, followed by `explode`
df.withColumn("ip", explode(rangeSequence($"start_ip_int", $"end_ip_int")))
```